# Administrator tools / updating other users details

Tags: php

I have implemented a functioning login and registration into a website template, but i am stuck on how to update other users details within the database using a form style basis?

For example is changing what group their in for the permissions, then a mod being able to give a 24 hour time out for chat/comments to standard users and so on.

Below is a very basic what i am talking about which iv done using the existing code just a different form, and its getting the username thats entered there that needs to be the 'id' for which row is edited?

I realise my code doesnt have what's needed but if anyone could point me in the right direction id much appreciate it.

```
<?php
require 'core/init.php';
include 'includes/overall/header.php';

if(!$user->hasPermission('admin')) {
    Redirect::to ('index.php');
}

if(Input::exists()) {
    if(Token::check(Input::get('token'))) {
        $validate = new Validate();
        $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'username' => array(
                'required' => true)
        ));

        if($validation->passed()) {

            try {
                $user->update(array(
                    'grouptest' => Input::get('group')
                ));
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }

            Session::flash('home', 'Your Name has been updated succssfully!.');
            Redirect::to('useraccount.php');

        } else {
            foreach($validate->errors() as $error) {
                echo $error, '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
}

?>


<form method="post" action="">
    <label for="username">Change user:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value=""/>
    <label for="group"> to group:</label>
    <select name="group" id="group">
        <option value="1">Standard user</option>
        <option value="2">Moderator</option>
        <option value="3">Administrator</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

Comment: do a `echo "<pre>"; var_dump($user); exit;` right after your include  and post the results here.

Answer (score 0):

i sorted it thanks. here is the whole rewrite of the code just for this.

It is basic but made it on its own.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require 'connect.php';
require 'security.php';


$records =array();

if(!empty($_POST)){
    if(isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['perms'])){
        $username  = trim($_POST['username']);
        $perms = trim($_POST['perms']);

        if(!empty($username) && !empty($perms)){

        $update = $db->query("UPDATE users2 SET perms = '$perms' WHERE username = '$username'");

            if($update){
                echo 'success';
                header('location: updatedb.php');
                die();
            } else {
                echo 'failed';
            }
        }
    }
}
if($results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users2")){
    if($results->num_rows){
        while($row = $results->fetch_object()){
            $records[] = $row;
        }
        $results->free();
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>updatedb</title>
    </head>
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="addtodb.php">Add to DB Form</a></li>
                <li><a href="giveadmin.php">Give Admin to Admin</a></li>
                <li><a href="updatedb.php">Update DB Form</a></li>
                <li><a href="deletedb.php">Delete from DB form</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <body>
        <h3>update database</h3>

        <?php
        if(!count($records)){
            echo 'no records';
        }else{
        ?>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Permission level</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($records as $r){
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo escape($r->username); ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo escape($r->perms); ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        <hr>

        <form method="post" action="">
            <label for="username">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value=""/>
            <label for="perms">Role:</label>
            <select name="perms" id="perms">
                <option value="1">Standard user</option>
                <option value="2">Moderator</option>
                <option value="3">Administrator</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Update">
            <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo Token::generate(); ?>">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```